# Vertically align a varible height text box next to a fixed height image

Tags: html, css, less, vertical-alignment

very common question I know, but I'm still struggling having read similar questions.

I have two divs (containing a variable height text box paragraph and a fixed height image) within a container div, as follows:

```
<div class="error-row row">
    <div class="error-value-col">
        <p class="error-value">{{error.message}}</p>
    </div>
    <a class="cross-link">
        <img class="cross" src="/assets/cross.png" alt="close">
    </a>
</div>
```

The accompanying LESS file is:

```
.error-row {
  border: 1px solid @po-yellow;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;

    .error-value-col {
      float:left;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: inline-block;
      width: calc(~'100% - 70px');

        .error-value {
          font-size: 10px;
          padding: 5px;

            p {
              margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
        }
    }

    .cross-link {
      padding: 0px;
      float: right;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 70px;

        img.cross {
          margin: auto;
          width: 70px;
          height: 70px;
          padding: 28.5px 27.5px 26.5px 27.5px;
          color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several different combinations of settings but none seem to work. I want whatever the element with the smallest height is (out of the image and text box) to centre alongside the taller element.

Thanks all.

EDIT: Clarification...I want the `error-value-col` and `cross-link` to be centred on the `error-row` container. This will of course be sized to the largest element out of the two, which could be either.

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide a fiddle

Comment: Do you want that `.error-value` will be vertical centered in `.error-value-col` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed approach and use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to obtain desired behaviour. Look at this [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvyzq2gd/) to see if it's acceptable for you (converted LESS in CSS there).

Apart design rules, relevant new ones to LESS code are the following:

```
.error-row {
  ...
  display:table;
  width:100%;

    .error-value-col {
      ...
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align:middle;

        .error-value {
          ...

            p {
              ...
            }
        }
    }

    .cross-link {
      ...
      display:table-cell;
      width:70px;
      vertical-align:middle;

        img.cross {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvyzq2gd/) to see all differences including erasing of floating.

**ALTERNATIVES**:

- Vertical aligning is (strangely) an hard topic in CSS, at least if
  you don't want to use relatively new [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model.
- Generally a very common method is to absolute positioning inner DIV
  with `top:50%` but due to fact that reference point is top-left
  corner, then you have to push up it of "*half of its height*" with a
  negative `margin-top`. This requires to have a fixed height of inner
  DIV, in order to set this negative margin to half of it.